# How to execute .exe using integrated terminal using shortcut key and tasks.json in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have application.exe in my folder which i want to execute from the terminal in vscode. Rather than opening integrated terminal manually and executing .exe, I want to bind this .exe execution to a keyboard shortcut in vscode.

So that if I press key shortcut (for ex. Ctrl+e), in the background my .exe will get executed automatically in the terminal.

Can anyone guid me on this, I am new in vscode.

Comment: so you want to run a command in the terminal directly without using tasks? Or run a task (that potentially runs a command in the terminal)?

Comment: hi @starball, Yes, I want to run a task. Task will run command in terminal (command for executing .exe).

Comment: you can find some pretty good documentation on how to do this here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks. Have you seen those docs? Was there anything in particular about them that you found hard to understand?